# dynamic data displayed in static UI

Tags: java, mysql, swing

My program uses Swing table to display data stored in MySQL, while the data is dynamic. I use a thread to repeatedly fetch data from database and refresh the table. I wonder if there are other much wiser methods to do this. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: The basic concept sounds fine, if you to get more sophisticated it comes down to been able what was added, updated and deleted and only updating the rows in the UI that have been effected.

Comment: there are 3rd side APIs that MySQL notified when data changed, never tried, Oracle has preimplemented this notifiers, nover tried too, nor talking about data quality, stable ...., (my view) by defaul loop is most managable

Comment: as you said, using a single thread to query  database and update the UI is appropriate, am I right? @mKorbel

Comment: Thanks for your advice and you have reminded me to think about the efficiency of the refresh process. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @Underthesun I would use a single thread for quering the database, but you will need to ensure that any updates you make to the UI are carried out in within the EDT

Comment: Surely all UI update task are invoked in EDT. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @Underthesun Not automatically. If you modify a TableModel, for example, its events a raised in the thread it was modified in, yu have to sync those updates back to the EDT yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as you said, using a single thread to query database and update the UI
>   is appropriate, am I right?

- not, [couldn't be true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049095/714968), or yes, [everything depends of latency and accessibily of data source(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6060678/714968)
- be sure that you'll update only visible Rectangle, cell in the JViewport, on periodical bases, other changes only to notify separatelly (JLabel, ToolTip, SystemTray e.g. ....)
- example about [JTable and Performance, called as ChristmastTree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988796/714968) (lost somwhere after Oracle cleanup Suns tutorial and codesources in last year), bases on standard `Workers Thread` (before `SwingWorker`...)

> I wonder if there are other much wiser methods to do this.

- as I already commnented there are Database notifiers thata firing event when add/ delete/ change is triggered in DB Engine, never tried, can't suggest if use that or not

Comment: it's a good thingy that the xmas tree example vanished in the darker regions of the net :-) Because it is an excellent example of how _not_ to tweak (going very dirty without the dirt having much effect)